# Permission denied while connect to serialport?

Tags: ruby, windows, serial-port, ruby-serialport

I'd like to connect to 3G modem using Ruby and the serialport gem.

My Ruby code:

```
require 'serialport'

class GSM
  sp = SerialPort.new('COM7', 9600)
  sp.read_timeout = 1500
  sp.write "AT\r\n"
  puts sp.read
end
```

I get this error after starting my script:

```
serialport.rb:25:in `create': Permission denied - \\.\COM7 (Errno::EACCES)
```

The IDE is run under administrator and the COM port is available from Putty and works fine. (I close Putty before running the script.)

Comment: is COM7 is a file or directory?

Comment: COM7 is virtual comport there my 3g modeb is connected

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs http://rubydoc.info/gems/serialport/SerialPort#new-class_method the port must be an integer or a full path to the device file. In your case I believe you want to replace 'COM7' with 6

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I've tried SerialPort.new(4, 9600) (connected device to another USB) and get same error serialport.rb:25:in `create': Permission denied - \\.\COM4 (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: In previous comment should be SerialPort.new(3, 9600)